# How can i convert below code to int from object in python?

Tags: python

I have been trying to change an object to string, so i first did the below code

```
total_deliveries_data.Order_ID = map(lambda x : x.str.split('-').str[1].str.split(',').str[0], total_deliveries_data.Order_ID)
total_deliveries_data
```

when i try the below code to convert the column to in.

```
total_deliveries_data["Order_ID"] = total_deliveries_data["Order_ID"].astype(str).astype(int)
```

i get

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<map object at 0x7f9f1f678f10>'

How can i sort this out

Comment: How does the data look like?

Comment: try: 
total_deliveries_data.Order_ID = str(map(lambda x : x.str.split('-').str[1].str.split(',').str[0], total))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.